# Why is my createIndex in Mongoose failing?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my cart controller I have the following segments of code:

```
const Cart = require('mongoose').model('Cart');
```

This works:

```
cart = await Cart.findOne({email:email});
```

But creating an index fails:

```
await Cart.createIndex({email: 1});
```

I get the following error:

```
car.controller#getCart TypeError: Cart.createIndex is not a function
at exports.getCart (backend\app\controllers\cart.controller.js:49:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at exports.authenticate (backend\app\controllers\user.controller.js:42:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

The literature says: createIndex() but createIndexes (plural) works;

Answer (score 0):

This issue because Mongoose's model (in this case is Cart) haven't function createIndex() so you should change createIndex() to createIndexes().

You can see docs here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.createIndexes